# Compilation error defining Matx<Vec3b, 2, 2> variable in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV v4.3.0 with gcc 9.3 on Ubuntu 18.04. In this code snippet:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::viz;
...
Matx<Vec3b, 2, 2> c{Color::red(), Color::green(), Color::blue(), Color::cyan()};
Matx<Vec3b, 2, 2> d{Color::red()};
Matx<Vec3b, 2, 2> e;
```

`c` and `d` definitions compile successfully, but `e` produces `call of overloaded ‘Vec(int)’ is ambiguous` error. Is this intentional?

Comment: I clicked a bit through the doc. of OpenCV. `Matx` provides a default constructor [cv::Matx::Matx()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/de/de1/classcv_1_1Matx.html#a03e916d291e4922a0e96ea638b32066e) as well as `Vec` does [cv::Vec::Vec()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d6/dcf/classcv_1_1Vec.html#a72bcb5232e9c11542886319edb9809a9). (`Vec3b` is `typedef Vec<uchar, 3> cv::Vec3b;`.) So far, what's documented. Does it happen as well when you use explicit scopes instead of `using namespace`? (Sorry, I'm no OpenCV expert but just a daily C++ user.)

Comment: `cv::Matx<cv::Vec3b, 2, 2> e;` produces the same error.

Comment: Ah, OK. That makes it more clear. Did you look into the source code to get a hint about this. Maybe, it's an issue worth to be filed as bug...

Comment: That source code is too scary to look. I hate template metasorcery...

Comment: I see. Usually, I would've had a look myself (out of curiosity) but I consider extensive template programming scaring as well. ;-)

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug, that should just default initialize everything with zeros. Seems not to be specific to ubuntu, nor to just OpenCV 4.3.x. I'll file a bug report. | Oh, and no metaprogramming there, just regular templates.

Comment: ... Although it might be the case that it just want primitive types for `_Tp`, although I don't see any explicit mentions of that, not to mention with explicit initialization it compiles...

Comment: Here's the issue filed: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17303